# How to set axes dimensions and locations in millimeters in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, point, figure

I need a figure with axis that are 80 mm wide and 60 mm tall while labels size is 12 points. The figure size has to be tightly cropped with no space outside the bounding box. How do I do this?

Also, I want two axes stacked with 10 mm spacing. How do I do that?

---

Point is the standard measure of 72 points per inch or 72/25.4 points per millimeter. 
Bounding box is smallest box that contains all the 'ink' of the figure.

Label sizes are easy as they are defined in points. fixing the figure size dependent of content size is hard.

This question is motivated by the need of creating multiple publication quality plots that **look exactly the same**. In addition, with latex rendering the characters can be exactly the same size and shape as the main text. This also applies to power point presentations. All boils down to figure size per font size that has to be fixed to standard units.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography) :

1 point (typography) =

SI units
352.78×10−6 m   352.778 μm

US customary units (Imperial units)

1.1574×10−3 ft  13.889×10−3 in

Answer (score 0):

You (I) don't want that. The best way to do this is to define the figure width in millimeters *and* axis width in millimeters and center the axis+labels. The height is irrelevant and that should be trimmed for whitespace.

This is just a start, the centering is missing. The next step is to clean up the code and make it a function (and add a 'trim height' and 'trim width' buttons to menu).

Basically this will be a two step process. On step one, the size of the axis is defined and the figure is plotted with labels. On step 2, the tightbox function is called and the width of the figure is calculated in inches. Then the figure is rescaled and a new axis location is determined.

```
import matplotlib
import pylab

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rc('figure', dpi=72)
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 10}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [
       r'\usepackage{lmodern}'    # latin modern, recommended to replace computer modern sans serif
       r'\usepackage{siunitx}',   # i need upright \micro symbols, but you need...
       r'\sisetup{detect-all}',   # ...this to force siunitx to actually use your fonts
       r'\usepackage{helvet}',    # set the normal font here
       r'\usepackage{sansmath}',  # load up the sansmath so that math -> helvet
       r'\sansmath']  # <- tricky! -- gotta actually tell tex to use! 

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 3 # ticklabel spacing between axis and text
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 2 # 

# APS, PRL, Two Columns
column_width_mm     = 86.4581 #mm
column_height_mm    = 2.5*column_width_mm

fig_hspace_mm       = 10 # mm
fig_wspace_mm       = 10 # mm

axis_width_mm       = 69.16648
axis_height_mm      = 43.09763

column_width_inch   = column_width_mm/25.4
column_height_inch  = column_height_mm/25.4

trim_height_below_mm = 0.0
trim_height_above_mm = 0.0

pylab.figure(num = 1, figsize=(column_width_inch, column_height_inch))

ax_0   = pylab.axes([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (1.0*fig_hspace_mm + 0.0*axis_height_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_1   = pylab.axes([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (2.0*fig_hspace_mm + 1.0*axis_height_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_2   = pylab.axes([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (3.0*fig_hspace_mm + 2.0*axis_height_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_3   = pylab.axes([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (4.0*fig_hspace_mm + 3.0*axis_height_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])

ax_0.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (1.0*fig_hspace_mm + 0.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_1.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (2.0*fig_hspace_mm + 1.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_2.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (3.0*fig_hspace_mm + 2.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_3.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (4.0*fig_hspace_mm + 3.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])

###########################
# plot figure here
###########################
pylab.sca(ax_0)
pylab.xlabel(r'$\mathrm{10pt~Test~Label~with~huge~symbols:}~\int~~\mathrm{[\frac{m}{s}]}$')
###########################

fig = pylab.gcf()

old_size        = fig.get_size_inches()
old_width_mm    = old_size[0]*25.4
old_height_mm   = old_size[1]*25.4 

bbox3 = ax_3.get_tightbbox(pylab.gcf().canvas.get_renderer())
bbox0 = ax_0.get_tightbbox(pylab.gcf().canvas.get_renderer())

trim_height_below_mm = ((bbox0.ymin)/72.0*25.4)
trim_height_above_mm = old_height_mm - ((bbox3.ymax+4)/72.0*25.4)

new_size        = fig.get_size_inches()
new_width_mm    = new_size[0]*25.4 
new_height_mm   = new_size[1]*25.4 - trim_height_below_mm - trim_height_above_mm

fig.set_size_inches(new_width_mm/25.4, new_height_mm/25.4, num = 1, forward=True)

print new_size, old_size, new_width_mm, new_height_mm
print trim_height_below_mm, trim_height_above_mm

column_width_mm     = new_width_mm
column_height_mm    = new_height_mm 

ax_0.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (1.0*fig_hspace_mm + 0.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_1.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (2.0*fig_hspace_mm + 1.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_2.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (3.0*fig_hspace_mm + 2.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])
ax_3.set_position([fig_wspace_mm/column_width_mm, (4.0*fig_hspace_mm + 3.0*axis_height_mm - trim_height_below_mm)/column_height_mm, axis_width_mm/column_width_mm, axis_height_mm/column_height_mm])

pylab.show()
```